# MIPS : parsing and modifying a string

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I have to write a program in MIPS where I have to open a file whose name is entered by the user and parse it,using the MARS simulator .
However, since the syscall 8 (which reads a string from user input) follows the semantics of the C function fgets, I have to remove the line feed \n character from the string before I can try and open the file.

I am able to parse the string (here I print the ASCII code of every character for debugging purpose ) . 
However when I try to change the line feed character into a NULL character with the line

```
sb $zero 0($t1)
```

Mars encounters an exception during execution :

> "Runtime exception at 0x00400050: address out of range 0x00000000"

If I comment out this line , the program runs fine and prints every  ascii code of the string.

```
.data

prompt : .asciiz "enter filename:\n"
lf : .asciiz "\n"
space : .asciiz " "

.text 

la $a0 prompt      # asking user for filename
jal print_string
jal read_string

la $t0 ($a0)   #copying the string address 
lb $t1 0($t0)  #loading the first  byte

parsing_string : #loop
beq $t1 0 remove_line_feed  # reaching the NULL character '\0'

move $a0  $t1   #printing the ascii code
li $v0 1 
syscall

la $a0 space  #printing a space
li $v0 4
syscall  

add $t0 $t0 1   # loading  
lbu $t1 ($t0)   # the next byte

j parsing_string

remove_line_feed :
sb $zero 0($t1)   # runtime exception if i uncomment  this line 
j end

end : 


li $v0 10     # syscall 10 : end program 
syscall



read_string :   #read a string in $a0

li $a1 100  # $a1 = maximum number of characters to read        
li $v0 8    # syscall 8  : fgets()
syscall 
jr $ra


print_string  :  #print string in $a0
li $v0 4      # syscall 4 : print string
syscall
jr $ra
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here, at this point of the program  the register  $t1 should  contain the address where the line feed character is written .
However  I may have misunderstood how the instructions save byte and load byte actually work.

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the asm code

```
sb $zero 0($t1)   # runtime exception if i uncomment  this line
```

you use `$t1` as the adress of the byte you want to clear.

But it is not. 
You used

```
la $t0 ($a0)   #copying the string address
```

and all your accesses use `$t0`.

At the end of your `parsing_string` function, you read the char at address `$t0` and *put it in `$t1`*:

```
lbu $t1 ($t0)   # the next byte
```

then you go back to `parsing_string`, test if t1 is 0

```
beq $t1 0 remove_line_feed  # reaching the NULL character '\0'
```

go to `remove_line_feed`

```
remove_line_feed :
sb $zero 0($t1)   # runtime exception if i uncomment  this line 
j end
```

Where you try to write zero at address `0+$t1` (that you just tested as being equal to zero).

And the simulator properly tells you that you try to write at address 0 and generates an error.

If you change your code to

```
remove_line_feed :
sb $zero 0($t0)   # runtime exception if i uncomment  this line 
j end
```

this will remove the runtime error.

But, it will not make your code correct. What you want to do is to clear the '\n' which is *just before* the `\0` and you code should be

```
remove_line_feed :
sb $zero -1($t0)    
j end
```

Alternatively, you can change the comparison and instead of searching the final `\0` of the string, search a 10 (ascii line feed) and replace the same char with 0.